# Add pod name to event tag in fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

Currently the events are enriched using `kubernetes_metadata`:

```
<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>
```

The current `tag` is `kubernetes.namespace`, I want it to be `kubernetes.namespace.pod_name`

I've added a `rewrite_tag_filter` but it doesn't work, and worse than that, it drops all the events:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $['kubernetes']['pod_name']
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag ${tag}.$1
  </rule>
</match>
```

I added `@type stdout` and the event does have `['kubernetes']['pod_name']` so I guess that's not the issue

---

update:
I've also tried the suggested answer and added:

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    # For future retagging.
    kubernetes_tag ${"kubernetes.%s.%s" % [record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"], record["kubernetes"]["container_name"]]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

At this point, I've printed out the event to `stdout` and it does contain a property named `kubernetes_tag` with the `namespace_name` and the `container_name` chained.
Now I've added the `rewrite_tag_filter` block:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key     kubernetes_tag
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag     $1
  </rule>
</match>
```

From this point on, no events are coming through and nothing is printed out, as if all events are dropped. Similarly to what I experienced at first.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
<filter kube.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    # For future retagging.
    kubernetes_tag ${"kubernetes.%s.%s.%s" % [record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"], record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["app"] || record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["k8s-app"] || record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["name"] || "unspecified-app-label", record["kubernetes"]["container_name"]]}
  </record>
</filter>

# Retag using the new field
<match kube.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key     kubernetes_tag
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag     $1
  </rule>
</match>
```

I don't suggest to use pod name alone in a tag, because often pod has multiple containers  each with own logging schema. I use namespace_name + container_name in tag instead.

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't explain what is incorrect in my setting, and I'll be happy to know :)

Comment: `enable_ruby` flag is supported in record_transformer only, so I first build the new field using transformer, and then make it a tag in a rewrite_tag_filter. This is for fluent 0.12

Comment: I was able to add the `kubernetes_tag` with the `namespace_name` and `container_name` and I can see the correct property was added to the event, however, as I've added the second block (`rewrite_tag_filter`) it looks like no events are coming through, similarly to the issue I've experienced in the first place

Comment: I've edited the question with more details information after trying your solution

Comment: how do you look for resulting events? try `<match kubernetes.**> @type stdout </match>`

Comment: add <match **> @type stdout </match> on the very beginning, before filter to check what's actually coming and how it's tagged. Once confirmed, add it after filter to check what meta is added and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the current tag is `namespace`?
You could try to check it in two steps:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern ^(?!\s*$).+
    tag kubernetes.$1
  </rule>
</match>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key kubernetes.pod_name
    pattern ^(?!\s*$).+
    tag ${tag}.$1
  </rule>
</match>
```

Also, I have changed the regex to non blank whitespaces strings.